# Construct a function with subindices

Tags: function-construction, formatting

I'm constructing a function that gives me subindices in output.
The function is `HAt`.

For example:

```
HAt[u == u0, t -> 0]
```

[image]

The function is constructed following:

```
HAt/:MakeBoxes[HAt[eq_, x_-> n_], StandardForm]:=
  RowBox[
    {SubscriptBox[
      RowBox[{"", ToBoxes[eq[[1]]], ")"}], 
      RowBox[{ToBoxes[x], "=", ToBoxes[n]}]], 
   "\[Equal]", 
   SubscriptBox[
      RowBox[{"(", ToBoxes[eq[[2]]], ")"}], 
      RowBox[{ToBoxes[x],"=",ToBoxes[n]}]]}]
```

So, the problema is when the right-hand (or left-hand) of my equation is a number. For example, if I put:

```
HAt[u == 0, t -> 0]
```

[image]

But I want some like this:

[image]

I think the ideia is put some condition at `eq[[2]]` when this term is a numerical term, some like that:

```
HAt/:MakeBoxes[HAt[eq_, x_ -> n_] /; eq[[2]]_Numeric, StandardForm] := 
  RowBox[
    {SubscriptBox[
       RowBox[{"(",ToBoxes[eq[[1]]],")"}], 
       RowBox[{ToBoxes[x], "=", ToBoxes[n]}]], 
       "\[Equal]",
       ToBoxes[eq[[2]]]}]
```

But the above doesn't work. How do I write the condition I want to enforce correctly?

Comment: Why not do this with `PatternTest`? Also `Numeric` isn't a thing... `NumericQ` is though.

Comment: Solved, thank you @b3m2a1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When playing with typesetting the most important thing is to keep your input unevaluated. In cases like `Hold @ HAt[...]` `MakeBoxes` won't know that `Hold` is there.

There are several things that can cause evaluation leaks:

- `ToBoxes[x]` will evaluate `x`, use `MakeBoxes`
- `eq[[1]]` will evaluate `eq`, use `lhs_ == rhs_` to match your equations
- `?NumericQ` will evaluate as well as opposed to e.g. `_Real` but the latter is not general enough. Fortunately there is `` System`Dump`HeldNumericQ `` :)

Here is how I'd do this:

```
HAt // ClearAll;
HAt /: MakeBoxes[HAt[lhs_ == rhs_, x_ -> n_], fmt : StandardForm] := With[
  { subscript = SubscriptBox[RowBox[{"(", #, ")"}], RowBox[{MakeBoxes[x, fmt], "=", MakeBoxes[n, fmt]}]] &
  }
, RowBox[{
    subscript @ MakeBoxes[lhs, fmt]
  , "\[Equal]"
  , If[System`Dump`HeldNumericQ[rhs], Identity, subscript] @ MakeBoxes[rhs, fmt]
  }]
]
```

[image]

[image]